# How to simply read html from any url via javascript and proxy?

Tags: javascript, php, proxy

This is my `proxy.php` file:

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url); // Avoid accessing the file system
echo file_get_contents($url); // You should probably use cURL. The concept is the same though
```

and my `reader.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = 'http://localhost/taboo.blue-world.pl/admin/proxy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.blue-world.pl')

    $.ajax({
        url      : url,
        type     : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data.results.result[1].category); // Do whatever you want here
    });
});
```

But it doesnt print anything. Can you help me solve it? I am not quite good with this.

Comment: is your url returning proper JSON formatted string or an HTML? If HTML, `dataType:json` will interfere, as your php does not return JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your are trying to get JSON response. Change `dataType` to `html`.

```
dataType: 'html'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to get an HTML response as JSON.

If the content is HTML you should turn you ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : url,
    type     : 'GET',
    dataType : 'html'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // data contains the html as a text
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either `dataType: 'html'` in reader.js  (to get HTML data)

OR

`echo(json_encode(file_get_contents($url)));` in proxy.php (for JSON data)

Answer (score 0):

Try `jQuery.parseJSON` for json format

```
 $.ajax({
        url      : url,
        type     : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(data.results.result[1].category); // Do whatever you want here
    });
    });
```